TarDisk 256G with Monterey OS
How do we Pear TarDisk 256G SD Expansion Card with our MacBook Pro running Monterey OS.

Please don't just repost a question which is on hold. Address the hold reason with an edit of the original question so it can be reviewed and reopened.
